# awk - tilde operator and hyphen. test below is not evaluating as expected

Tags: bash, awk

In awk I am attempting to locate a string that consists of a hyphen and zero-to-many characters. I am using the tilde operator to do the comparison and expecting to return the correct field based on the pattern

```
/[-][a-zA-Z]*/
```

The test:

```
echo "test -abc" | awk '{for (i=0; i<=NF; i++){if ($i ~   /[-][a-zA-Z]*/){print $(i+1);exit}}}'
```

It is consistently returning "test".

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't `$0` the whole input line?

Comment: change start index from `0` to `1` and test until `<NF`.  Your test input is missing the field after match.  Perhaps you want to fix it as well.

Comment: thanks @karakfa this was the right direction.  `i=1; i<=NF; i++`  along with `print{ $(i)` fixed it. makes perfect sense. face palm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a `sed` solution

```
echo "apple -korn -bash  orange strawbery -tsh  " |
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]{1,}[^-]*[[:blank:]]{1,}/ /g;s/^[^-]*-/-/'
```

which gives you

```
-korn -bash -tsh
```

Comment: @sysam, much cleaner. new to bash and working things out as I go. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`grep` alternative

```
echo "apple -korn -bash  orange strawbery -tsh" | grep -o '[-][a-zA-Z]*' | xargs

-korn -bash -tsh
```